# Adding stored procedure to local database

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

I've created a stored procedure by SA login. I can execute this stored procedure when I'm logged as SA. But when I'm logged via my login, I can't execute it, it returns error

> The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'fcd_up_MBK', database 'workdb', schema 'dbo'.

How can I grant permission when I'm logged via my login?

Moreover, I can't see this stored procedure in `Datebases > workdb > Programmability > Stored Procedures`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to logon as `sa` and `GRANT EXECUTE` to your schema

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON SCHEMA::userSchema TO db_execproc;
```

userSchema would be your login id schema, is your login id a member of dbo?  If so then use `dbo` as the schema.

or to brute force it:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON <procedurename> to <username>
```